# Seaborn multi-plot grid with unrelated datasets

Tags: python, grid, seaborn

I would like to arrange ~100 regression plots into a grid, the input is a csv file where the first ~100 columns are each regressed on the last column. I just want the grid to save space, there is no logical arrangement of my variables into rows and columns and it is not a variable with 100 levels either.

This example from the seaborn documentation looks almost like what I want (replacing pointplot with lmplot),

```
attend = sns.load_dataset("attention")
g = sns.FacetGrid(attend, col="subject", col_wrap=4, height=2, ylim=(0, 10))
g.map(sns.pointplot, "solutions", "score", order=[1, 2, 3])
```

but I cannot figure out how to pass the columns. I tried using an array of column names but it did not work, and I'm not sure if a loop is a better idea. Thank you in advance for any tips!

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

MRI_data = pd.read_csv('MRI_data.csv',sep=';')
y_list = ["brainstem","3rdventricle",...]
g = sns.FacetGrid(MRI_data, col="TIV", col_wrap=4)
g.map(sns.lmplot(x="Age",y=y_list, data=MRI_data))
```

and it gives me this warning:
2022-01-21 11:26:15,175 [20551] WARNING  py.warnings:99: [JupyterRequire] /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:136: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)

Comment: You probably need to convert your dataframe to [long form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) and then use the newly created 'variable' column for `y=` or `hue=`

Comment: I wanted to avoid that because it would create a 30,000 row dataframe but it does seem like the only option. Thank you, also for the link, I'll try that!